# Record SWT MouseEnter/Exit events on a Composite with a FillLayout

Tags: java, swt, mouseevent

I have a `Composite` on which I'd like to track `SWT.MouseEnter` and `SWT.MouseExit` events. The `Composite`, however, has another `Composite` inside it which consumes the entirety of the region, due to a `FillLayout`.

Some sample code to illustrate what it is I'm doing:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class EventListenerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        // Set up the outer Composite
        Composite outerComp = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        FillLayout fl = new FillLayout();
        // fl.marginHeight = 15;
        // fl.marginWidth = 15;
        outerComp.setLayout(fl);

        // Set up a nested Composite
        Composite innerComp = new Composite(outerComp, SWT.BORDER);

        // Set a listener on the outer Composite for a MouseEnter event
        outerComp.addListener(SWT.MouseEnter, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                System.out.println("Mouse ENTER event");
            }

        });

        // Similarly, for a MouseExit event
        outerComp.addListener(SWT.MouseExit, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                Composite comp = (Composite) e.widget;
                // Don't report if positioned over a child control
                for (Control child : comp.getChildren()) {
                    if (!child.getBounds().contains(new Point(e.x, e.y)))
                        System.out.println("Mouse EXIT event");
                }
            }

        });

        outerComp.pack();
        outerComp.layout();

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
          if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
          }
        }

        display.dispose();
        return;
      }
}
```

Unfortunately, due to the fact that `innerComp` fills the entirety of its parent, `outerComp` never does record the mouse enter/exit events *unless* I expose a little bit of its "area".

I'm able to expose a little bit of `outerComp` by creating some margins on its `FillLayout` (commented out lines 21-22), but this is really not ideal. For aesthetic reasons, I can't have huge margins on `outerComp`, and reducing the margin size to 1 doesn't consistently detect the mouse events if I'm moving my mouse over the composite quickly (I have to move my mouse *very* slowly over the 1px margin for it to trigger).

From a design perspective on my project, I'm not actually supposed to know what `outerComp` contains (or how deep the controls nest), so setting the event listeners on its children also isn't ideal.

Is there any way I can still track these mouse events on the `outerComp` if it has a `FillLayout` consuming all of its area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is add a filter to the `Display` and in the handler, check if the `Widget` that is the source of the `Event` is a child of your `Composite`.

This should give you an idea of how to do it:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));

    final Composite left = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    Composite right = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    left.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));
    right.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        new Label(left, SWT.NONE).setText("label-" + i);
        new Label(right, SWT.NONE).setText("label-" + i);
    }

    display.addFilter(SWT.MouseMove, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            if (isChildOrSelf(e.widget, left))
                System.out.println(e);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();
}

private static boolean isChildOrSelf(Widget child, Composite parent)
{
    if(child == parent)
        return true;

    for (Control c : parent.getChildren())
    {
        if (c instanceof Composite)
        {
            boolean result = isChildOrSelf(child, (Composite)c);
            if (result)
                return true;
        }
        else if (c == child)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I read somewhere about using a display filter, but couldn't quite figure it out. Thank you!